# Image icon on the right side of UIBarButtonItem on toolbar (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

How can I display the image icon on the right side of UIBarButtonItem on toolbar?

```
    let button = UIBarButtonItem(
        image_name: "next_item",
        title: "Continue",
        target: self,
        action_selector: nil
    )
```

I tried to manipulate `button.imageInsets`, but it changed nothing for me.

Swift 3, iOS 8+.

I expect the result like this:
[image]

Comment: title:"Continue >"

Comment: @iDeveloper nice solution =) but it will be wrong size and shape.

Comment: simply use custome view and use lable for title and imageview for your image

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the UIBarButton using a custom view.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617151-init

In the custom view, put a `UILabel` and then the `UIImageView` by the side.

Answer (score -1):

Use attributted string and add your image with String and display it on title

```
// create an NSMutableAttributedString that we'll append everything to
let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Start of text")

// create our NSTextAttachment
let image1Attachment = NSTextAttachment()
image1Attachment.image = UIImage(named: "Icon.png")

// wrap the attachment in its own attributed string so we can append it
let image1String = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1Attachment)

// add the NSTextAttachment wrapper to our full string, then add some more text.
fullString.append(image1String)
fullString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "End of text"))

// draw the result in a label
yourLabel.attributedText = fullString
```

Comment: Are you sure, that I can use Attibured String with default UIBarButtonItem view? `button.title` is `String`. Should I create custom view with label for this method?

Comment: Yes u can as use or try it once.